# Catching and modifying stderr sent from external JAR

Tags: java, jar, stderr

Is there a way for me to *intercept* the STDERR stream that is being used from an external JAR file?

My situation is that I have *my own* program using STDERR for XYZ, and an external JAR that uses STDERR for ABC.  I want to merge both so that they are formatted correctly for the end user, but I cannot figure out how to *catch* or *redirect* or (what is the right term?) the JAR's STDERR?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard error stream in java programs is `System.err` and standard output stream is `System.out`.

You can override these both using the [System.setErr(java.io.PrintStream)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setErr%28java.io.PrintStream%29) and System.setOut to a PrintStream object. But this will be replaced globally. Provide an implementation of a PrintStream that will do the formatting and set this as an standard error stream for both.

If you have two different processes, then you can get another [processes's error](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getErrorStream%28%29) stream (as an input stream) read content from it (fromat it) and write it to your standard error stream.

Comment: The problem here is that I don't know when/what each JAR is printing.  E.g. I need to know which JAR they're coming from so that I can actually format them correctly.  No way to detect what is coming from which JAR?

Answer (score 0):

Not an easy solution, but you could create a classloader, java agent or preprocessor that modifies the bytecode of selected classes and replaces all references to the static field System.err to access your custom output stream.